# udisks-part-id timeout error in tty

Tags: 14.04, usb, tty, udev, udisks

I'm running 14.04 and I've gotten the following error when logging into a tty session after typing my password but before the command prompt showed up:

```
[198877.466429] systemd-udevd[25302]: timeout 'udisks-part-id /dev/sdb'
[198878.467543] systemd-udevd[25302]: timeout: killing 'udisk-part-id /dev/sdb' [20816]
[198878.581606] systemd-udevd[25302]: 'udisks-part-id /dev/sdb' [20816] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
```

The machine is a laptop with one hard drive. I searched for a command to show me what sdb even was and someone entioned `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` so I ran that and here is the line that mentioned sdb:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 18 03:07 usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0 -> ../../sdb
```

What does the error mean? My best guess is something is wrong with the usb card and/or the driver for it? Assuming that's the case, how do I get enough information about the card to find out if there is a new driver or something?

*Edit:* When I said "tty session" I meant I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and logged in that way, (I did that to kill a program that was making my GUI session unusably slow.)

The only MMC card that was plugged in at the time the error happened is built in to the laptop. There was no card inserted into it either.

There's no mention of sbd in `/etc/fstab/`, just some stuff about partitions on sda.

I looked in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and the only `.rules` files there were `70-persistent-cd.rules` and `70-persistent-net.rules`

As mentioned before, the MMC card is built-in so I didn't remove it. I ran `sudo udevadm test --action=add /sys/class/block/sdb` anyway and got this output:

```
calling: test
version 204
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          204
file size:         5774243 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1271747 bytes
nodes              4502416 bytes
load module index
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-crda.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-hyperv-hotadd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-inputattach.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-joystick.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-2.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules
GOTO 'libgphoto2_usb_end' has no matching label in: '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules'
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-virtualbox-dkms.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-virtualbox.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-xdiagnose.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-hpmud.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-pcmcia.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gnome-bluetooth-rfkill.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/62-google-cloudimg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/66-xorg-synaptics-quirks.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id --export %p', replacing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules:89
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xorg-vmmouse.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-pcmcia-device-blacklist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-platform-serial-whitelist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qdl-device-blacklist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-serial-adapters-greylist.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-nm-olpc-mesh.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-graphics-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-brltty.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-keyboard-configuration.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-ucm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-hid-rebind.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-libgpod.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-dell.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-fujitsu.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-gateway.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-ibm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-lenovo.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-toshiba.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/98-osscuse.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-steam-controller-perms.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 40045 bytes strings
33093 strings (275017 bytes), 29157 de-duplicated (238909 bytes), 3937 trie nodes used
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules:3
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0: if_class 8 protocol 6
GROUP 6 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:50
LINK 'disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:43
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:57
LINK 'disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:58
IMPORT builtin 'blkid' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:72
error: /dev/sdb: No medium found
IMPORT 'udisks-part-id /dev/sdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules:84
starting 'udisks-part-id /dev/sdb'
'udisks-part-id /dev/sdb' [13520] exit with return code 0
RUN '/lib/udev/hdparm' /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules:2
handling device node '/dev/sdb', devnum=b8:16, mode=0660, uid=0, gid=6
preserve permissions /dev/sdb, 060660, uid=0, gid=6
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/block/8:16' to '../sdb'
found 'b8:16' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fdisk\x2fby-id\x2fusb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0'
creating link '/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0' to '/dev/sdb'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0' to '../../sdb'
found 'b8:16' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fdisk\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0'
creating link '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0' to '/dev/sdb'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0' to '../../sdb'
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sdb
DEVTYPE=disk
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=Multi-Card
ID_MODEL_ENC=Multi-Card\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=0158
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_7-usb-0_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=1.00
ID_SERIAL=Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=20071114173400000
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=ums-realtek
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Generic-
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic-
ID_VENDOR_ID=0bda
MAJOR=8
MINOR=16
SUBSYSTEM=block
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
USEC_INITIALIZED=88805
run: '/lib/udev/hdparm'
unload module index
```

**Edit 2:**

Looking through `/var/log/syslog` I see lines like the following showing up about once a minute:

```
Jul 20 03:33:28 ryan-PC kernel: [  398.876900] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jul 20 03:33:28 ryan-PC kernel: [  398.879147] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jul 20 03:33:28 ryan-PC kernel: [  398.879152] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I tried commenting out line 36 of `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` and restarting and those lines are still showing up and the output of `sudo udevadm test --action=add /sys/class/block/sdb` looks the same including the line that says `error: /dev/sdb: No medium found`

The original timeout error hasn't shown up since though, (before or after I commented out line 36.)

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Zanna No I did not.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you show comes from the fact that you have a udev execution timing issue associated with importing the device's properties of `/dev/sdb`. I suspect you can see similar and perhaps more explicit errors in your `/var/log/syslog`.

Look up your udev rule: `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`

- a symbolic link is correctly created at line 43 for `/../../sdb` as reflected by yr output:  `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdb`
- `path_id` is correctly imported (as device property - see `man udev`) on line 57
- a symbolic link is correctly created at line 58 for device path: `disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0`
- the entry causing the error is on line 72, when that block device's attributes are imported with `blkid`.

For Ubuntu 14.04.4 desktop installs, this is:

```
# probe filesystem metadata of disks
KERNEL!="sr*", IMPORT{builtin}="blkid"
```

From this [report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1091513) try commenting line 36 of `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`, so that instead of relying on `ata_id  --export $devnode` to import device properties, `udev` will fall back on `usb_id`.

If this is successful in suppressing errors, bear in mind that that change to `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` is not permanent and maybe lost as you run upgrades. Apparently this is a well documented problem on several distros. Not sure it qualifies as a bug. It maybe be hardware or firmware related. You may want to research that part.